# How to extract specific array keys and values to another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays like so:

```
array( array(), array(), array(), array() );
```

the arrays inside the main array contain 4 keys and their values. The keys are the same among all arrays like this:

```
array( 'id' => 'post_1',
       'desc' => 'Description 1',
       'type' => 'type1',
       'title' => 'Title'
     );

array( 'id' => 'post_2',
       'desc' => 'Description 2',
       'type' => 'type2',
       'title' => 'Title'
     );
```

So I want to create another array and extract the `id` and `type` values and put them in a new array like this:

```
array( 'post_1' => 'type1', 'post_2' => 'type2'); // and so on
```

The keys in this array will be the value of `id` key old arrays and their value will be the value of the `type` key.

So is it possible to achieve this? I tried searching [php.net Array Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) but I don't know which function to use?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just use a good ol' loop:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($oldArray as $entry) {
    $newArray[$entry['id']] = $entry['type'];
}
```

Comment: I upvoted the question and the answer. How can I downvote PHP for not providing a better method?

Comment: @Olivier'Ölbaum'Scherler Good news: php has provided a function for this -- see the higher upvoted answer.

Answer (score 132):

PHP 5.5 introduced an array function that does exactly what you want.
I'm answering this in hopes that it may help someone in future with this question.

The function that does this is [`array_column`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).
To get what you wanted you would write:

```
array_column($oldArray, 'type', 'id');
```

To use it on lower versions of PHP either use the accepted answer or take a look at how this function was implemented in PHP and use this library: https://github.com/ramsey/array_column

Comment: Additionally, you can wrap that in array_unique to filter out dupliate values :) http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @deceze's simple loop, for those poor folks still on a <5.5 version of PHP (like me), and not needing the excellent full implementation from Ramsey above, you could also use this:

```
$new_array = array_map(function ($elem) {
    return $elem['your_key'];
}, $old_array);
```

Comment: This answer does not populate the keys as required in the asked question.  This answer is the <5.5 equivalent of `array_column($old_array, 'your_key')`, but `array_map()` cannot custom assign keys in its returned array.

Comment: You are of course correct @mickmackusa. I was so focused on my own problem, which was to get only values, that I posted before reading the question carefully. Rookie mistake.

Comment: You have the power to self-delete this answer.