# How to get array values between 2 keys and put into string

Tags: php

Im looking for a way to take a php array and pass the values between a couple of array keys and save into a string.

```
$array1 = array(0=>'sometext',
                1=>'1703',
                2=>'North',
                3=>5th',
                4=>'st',
                5=>'sometext')


I know the starting key and the end key in my script
$startnum = 1;
$endnum  = 4;
I need to get this
$string = '1703 North 5th st'
```

without changing the keys in the array because i have to iterate over the array again later. I am currently using array splice but it removes the items and key in the array so when i iterate over the array again the keys and values are all messed up. Please let me know if i need a better explanation.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328780/how-to-extract-specific-array-keys-and-values-to-another-array?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the segment of interest using [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice), then collapse it using [`implode`](http://php.net/implode):

```
$string = implode(' ', array_slice($array1, $startnum, $endnum-$startnum));
```

Note that `array_slice` takes an offset and a length, so the length is computed as the end less the start.

Answer (score 3):

You could always use a basic `for` loop:

```
$str = "";
for ($i = $startnum; $i < $endnum; $i++){
    $str .= $array1[$i]." ";
}
$str .= $array1[$endnum];
```