# Get multi column from array php, Alternate of array_column

Tags: php, arrays, array-column

I have used this function to get multi column from array. Alternate of array_column. I have created this function as array_column not work according my requirement.

My Data

```
$students = 
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 498
            [uuid] => 6cb91efd-9111-4be8-a2d7-80d3edeed732
            [name] => Andrew A. Blaine
            [email] => student14@gmail1.com
            [usertype_id] => 6
            [first_name] => Andrew A.
            [last_name] => Blaine
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 499
            [uuid] => 208764a0-c53d-404b-ad05-ee7cba28a51c
            [name] => Billie C. Heath
            [email] => student15@gmail1.com
            [usertype_id] => 6
            [first_name] => Billie C.
            [last_name] => Heath
        )
)
```

My function

```
  public function filterArrayByKeys($data, $keys = array()) {
    $filterData = array_map(function($e) use ($keys) {
        if (is_object($e)) {
            foreach ($keys as $key) {
                $filterArray[$key] = $e->$key;
            }
            return $filterArray;
        } else {
            foreach ($keys as $key) {
                $filterArray[$key] = $e[$key];
            }
            return $filterArray;
        }
    }, $data);
    return array_values(array_unique($filterData, SORT_REGULAR));
 }
 $students = $this->filterArrayByKeys($students, ['id', 'name', 'email']);
```

Now my result as I expected is:

```
$students = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 498
            [name] => Andrew A. Blaine
            [email] => student14@gmail1.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 499
            [name] => Billie C. Heath
            [email] => student15@gmail1.com
        )
)
```

You can use this function to get multi columns from array.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Function which will work as array_column but for multiple keys, is the question

Comment: So... this is a non-question?  You posted a working technique (an answer to a problem) as a question.  There is no question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is custom function to achieve this,

```
public function filterArrayByKeys(array $input, array $column_keys)
{
    $result      = array();
    $column_keys = array_flip($column_keys); // getting keys as values
    foreach ($input as $key => $val) {
         // getting only those key value pairs, which matches $column_keys
        $result[$key] = array_intersect_key($val, $column_keys);
    }
    return $result;
}

$a = $this->filterArrayByKeys($students, ['id','name','email']);
print_r($a);
```

[array_flip](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) — Exchanges all keys with their associated values in an array
[array_intersect_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) — Computes the intersection of arrays using keys for comparison

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 498
            [name] => Andrew A. Blaine
            [email] => student14@gmail1.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 499
            [name] => Billie C. Heath
            [email] => student15@gmail1.com
        )

)
```

Working [demo](https://eval.in/1098863).

[Source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php#118763).