# Remove unwanted elements from subarrays in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, slice, unset, sub-array

I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
[
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'John',
        'address' => 'Some address 1'
        'city' => 'NY'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Jack',
        'address' => 'Some address 2'
        'city' => 'NY'
    ]
    ...
  
    [ ... ]
]
```

How can I remove elements in all subarrays and only retain the **id** and **name** keys with their values?

Comment: Do you actually need *filtering* (by some value) or are you looking to simply *extract* the two keys?

Comment: maybe the wrong term "filter" - what i'm lookng for is keeping only those 2 keys in that multidim array

Comment: Loop and unset all other. or use array_column

Comment: A simple `foreach` where you build a new array would be the best choice if you also want to keep the original array intact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this work?

```php
$result = array_map(function($arr) {
    return [
        'id' => $arr['id'],
        'name' => $arr['name']
    ];
}, $orig_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to retain the first two associative elements, so you can make `array_slice()` calls within `array_map()`. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kh6aH))

```
var_export(
    array_map(fn($row) => array_slice($row, 0, 2), $array)
);
```

---

Or mapped called of `array_intersect_key()` against an establish whitelist array. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mRJ0T))

```
$keep = ['id' => '', 'name' => ''];
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => array_intersect_key($row, $keep),
        $array
    )
)
```

---

Or, you could use array destructuring inside of a classic `foreach()` and make iterated `compact()` calls. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/f6vMP))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as ['id' => $id, 'name' => $name]) {
    $result[] = compact(['id', 'name']);
}
var_export($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to edit the same array in place, you can simply iterate over them and `unset` them.

```
<?php 

$preserve_keys = ['id','name'];

foreach($arr as &$data){
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        if(!in_array($key,$preserve_keys)){
            unset($data[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you want it as a separate result, loop over and add it to the new array.

```
<?php

$new_result = [];

foreach($arr as $data){
    $new_result[] = [
        'id' => $data['id'],
        'name' => $data['name']
    ];
}

print_r($new_result);
```